# Why does AWS RDS still shows burst balance 0 with disk size 2TB gp2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

According to what I know about gp2 from AWS docs ([link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/understanding-burst-vs-baseline-performance-with-amazon-rds-and-gp2/)), gp2 disks have burst capabilily when they are smaller than 1000GB.
After disk is bigger 1000GB, baseline performance exceeeds 3000 IOPS burst performance, so that "burst" term cannot apply.

However, as I see on my current prod database with 2TB gp2 storage, burst balance still somehow apply to me, and storage is considerably faster while burst balance is more than 0.

Apparently, there are changes in AWS Burst term. Does anybody knows modern terms, so I can plan my hardware accordingly?

[image: burst balance]
[image: metrics]
[image: metrics]

Comment: If you check directly in CloudWatch Metrics, not RDS console, does it show same?

Comment: @Marcin metric itself does not really matter. What's important is that it's clearly visible that database IO degrades when balance gets 0. Which means balance actually has effect.

Comment: What db instance do you use?

Comment: @Marcin db.m5.2xlarge

Comment: `db.m5` are Nitro based instance. Burst metric should not be reported at all for you. Its confusing. I think if you don't get satisfactory answer on SO, may need to contact AWS support to look into this.

Comment: @Marcin Thing is than AWS support is 7% of monthly bill, which means I would have to spend like 2K USD for asking the thing that should actually be described in their docs. So I gave chance to SO first :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I made request to AWS support about this.
It was a lengthy thread where I got to know several important facts.
I have saved my conversation at this [link](https://github.com/snowindy/aws-support-cases/tree/main/aws-burst-iops-case), so it's not lost for community.

Answer: **burts balance may still apply for storage bigger than 1TB, because there may be several volumes to serve storage space. If volume is smaller than 1TB - burst balance gets utilized for that volume.**

Other facts that were obscure for me:

- database may look like it's capped by IOPS limits (due internal IOPS submerge operation), but in reality it may be capped by network throughput.
- network throughput is gueranteed by EBS-Optimized. At RDS docs you won't find explicit tables how instances relate to throughput, but it's there on EBS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-optimized.html)
- For some of the instances that are nitro-based, EBS-Optimized allows to work at maximum throughput for class for 30 minutes each 24 hours. For smaller instances it means that for 30 minutes database may go skyrocket performance, comprared to poor baseline.

Comment: Thanks for following up and updating this. When I first read it, i was comparing burst credit to some previous AWS battlescars.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into that issue with EFS, provisioning enough capacity (storage and throughput) is one thing, provisioning burst capacity is something else. In this case it appears that you are running into the same issue. Exceeding your burst capacity. If you have a read-heavy application, consider using a replica or a caching scheme. Alternatively you can increase your 2TB disk to 4TB or look into provisioned iops solution.

Comment: For gp2 greater then 1TB burst capacity should be irrelevant. How you can "exceed" it? Do you have more information or some reference on this?

Comment: GP2 max iops is 16000. If you are exceeding that you will hit burst capacity limits. io1 will alleviate that. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/best-storage-practices-for-running-production-workloads-on-hosted-databases-with-amazon-rds-or-amazon-ec2/

Comment: @MichaelQuale According to your link, and my link in the question "The burst feature is limited to volumes equal to or less than 1 TiB of storage". However my storage is 2TB and I still see some burst impact. I should not feel this impact, according to articlese. So I ask my question to clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

From the screen capture, I can see that AWS is already delivering the performance they promised for your instance ( 6K IOPS, consistently )

So the question remains is why there is still burst performance that let you burst up to > 11K IOPS ( the 7:00 - 9:00 timeframe ) for a limitted time

My guess is that the 3K IOPS burst limit is only for instances with less than 1TB. For instance of bigger size, you can burst up to "Baseline performance + 3k IOPS" ( around 9k in your case ) until the IO credit runs out. I have not seen any document around this though

Comment: Right. It's indeed nice there is some "unexpected burst", but fact it's undocumented and contradicts current docs - is not cool, as rules should be clear for everybody.